# How to search a large String

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Hi I have the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
var allSearchResults = [];
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(paramm)
{
loadXMLDoc("ajax_info.txt",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var txt=xmlhttp.responseText;

    if (txt.match(paramm)!= -1){
            //store all instances in allSearchResults array Here
     }
        else{
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = paramm;
            }

    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('CXS101289')">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax_info.txt

```
CXS101289_5_R1A06_100628150914
CXS101289_5_R1A06_100628343414
CXS10rfe_5_R1A06_100628150955
CXS101349_5_R1A06_100628150432
CXS154f89_5_R1A06_100628150914
CXS101289_5_R1A06_10062456914
CXS101369_5_R1A06_100628150914
CXS15679_5_R1A06_100628150914
```

So I want to search this file for the "CXS101289". So after I have run this method, the "allsearchResults" array shall contain `["CXS101289_5_R1A06_100628343414","CXS101289_5_R1A06_100628343414","CXS101289_5_R1A06_10062456914"]`

Any smart idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for

```
result = txt.match(new RegExp("\\b" + param + "\\S*", "g"));
```

for example after

```
param = "x";
txt = "x_1 y_2 z_3 x_4 yx_5 z_6 x_7";
result = txt.match(new RegExp("\\b" + param + "\\S*", "g"))
```

result is `["x_1", "x_4", "x_7"]`

Note that if param is going to contain charaters that have a special meaning for a regular expression (for example `*` or `+` or `]`) then you have to escape them by prepending a backslash.

The initial `\b` is needed to be sure that your search key is only accepted at the beginning of an item.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findMatched(text, keyword) {
  var arr = text.split('\n');
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(arr[i].match(keyword)) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//...and in your code
if (txt.match(paramm)!= -1){
  allSearchResults = findMatched(txt, paramm);
}
```

It is the only way I can see it solve. But maybe you already taught of this and where asking something else.

Comment: Another quick question, how can i write the symbol " in a text string?
For example Var example = "hello " end"

Can you link to a site where I can see all these symbols?

Comment: I want to add the following to a string <a href="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/example_1">    Example_1</a>

Comment: @Anders: You can escape the inner double with a backslash. For example `var example = "hello \" end";`